# How can I use complex types referencing generic type

Tags: delphi, generics, fpc

Consider the following types

```
type
  TRecs = array[0..100000] of TRec;
  PRecs = ^TRecs;

  TRecObject = class
  private
    fRecs: PRecs;
  public
    constructor Create;
    property    Recs: PRecs read fRecs;
  end;
```

I would like to make TRec a generic parameter. The problem is that I need to place   outside of the class scope. Because something like

```
 T<MyType>Object = class
 private
   fRecs: ^array[0..100000] of MyType;
 public
    property    Recs: ^array[0..100000] of MyType read fRecs
 end
```

is not possible.

Making PRecs a parameter also is not an option because there is TRec-related code in my actual object.

Is there a solution in modern Object Pascal? And if not, just curious is there any other generic-enabled language that can solve something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
type
  TMyObject<T> = class
  public
    type
      PArr = ^TArr;
      TArr = array[0..100000] of T;
  private
    fRecs: PArr;
  public
    property Recs: PArr read fRecs
  end;
```

That said, I can't see the point of that class. You could just use `TList<T>` from `Generics.Collections`.

And if your need an array, then you can use a dynamic array: `TArray<T>` or `array of T`, as you prefer.

Comment: :) you were quicker. and closer to the question with that pointer stuff.

Comment: You understood it perfectly :)

Comment: There is no generics.collections in FPC. In FPC there are some generic containers in unit fgl though, Delphi's generics.collections is not compatible to fgl.

Comment: @marco I think the question is about delphi and is mis-tagged. But I don't really know. Not sure how a question can be about both.

Comment: @David_Heffernan, I think as long as the fpc team considers delphi compatibility a high priority, asking about both makes sense. As for your solution, it worked well in fpc

Comment: OK. I understand now. Tagging both Delphi and fpc can be confusing. Sometimes it means the asker is using fpc but wants delphi devs to read the Q. Perhaps clarification in the Q would help. Anyway, I think it's all good here!

Comment: Note I commented to the List<T> suggestion, not the rest. Btw, generics are substantially better in FPC/trunk then in released versions

Comment: @Marco How do fpc generics compare with Delphi? Does fpc have fewer compiler bugs?!

Comment: Then what? D2009?, sure. :-)  FPC originally had a more C++ like approach to generics without constraints. (this is pre D2009) Then Delphi added generics too, in an incompatible way, and the current situation is a hybrid where constraints are parsed but ignored. (at the expense of finding many problems only at specialization). At least it doesn't have bugs like QC 99703 :-)

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Even in XE3 there are plenty of generics compiler bugs. It seems like a total bug factory.

Comment: Generics is a difficult subject. Basically you take the language and add a whole dimension to everything. It took the various C++ compilers also a long time to get it to a stable level.

Answer (score 2):

You got your generic syntax a bit muddled up. Try this:

```
  TRecArray<T> = array[0..100000] of T;

  TGenericRecObject<T> = class
  private
    FRecs: TRecArray<T>;
  public
    property Recs: TRecArray<T> read FRecs;
  end;
```

Comment: .... but your dynamic type declared outside the class is quite nice. Also, question seems to want to use pointers. I think that's because @Maksee hasn't come across dynamic arrays yet.

Comment: You could be right. I avoid pointers if I can and dynamic array types are indeed wonderful in that respect.

Comment: That's correct, I need pointers. Let's say for historical reasons :)